# Not able to insert charts using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code which is supposed to insert charts based on a table.It used to work but now it is throwing a run time error "438" Object doesn't support property or method"

```
Range("P4:AC6").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(276, xlAreaStacked).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'BU wise Summary'!$P$4:$AC$6")
ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 283
ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
Sheets("Charts").Select
Cells(204, 7).Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Can someone let me know what is the error?

Comment: Because you are running this code on [Excel v. < 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228277.aspx)?

Comment: Oh....yeah , can you post that as an answer so that i can close this thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shapes.AddChart2` was [added in Excel 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228277.aspx).

Either run the macro on Excel 2013+ or use [the older way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203725(v=office.11).aspx#odc_xl_manipulatecharts_usingembeddedcharts).

Comment: Thank you, I wrote the code in excel 2013 long back.. :-)